# Multiple custom constructors - Hibernate JPA TypedQuery

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

Is it possible to write a `TypedQuery` which contains multiple custom constructors? For example if you want to create objects which contain an id and another object, such as:

```
TypedQuery<ChapterWithBookId> query = em.createQuery(
  "SELECT new " + ChapterWithBookId.class.getName() + "(book.id, new example.Chapter(chapter.id, "
  + "chapter.size"
  + ")) "
  + "FROM " + Book.class.getName() + " AS book JOIN " + Chapter.class.getName() + " AS chapter WHERE "
  + "book.id IN :ids", ChapterWithBookIds.class)
  .setParameter("ids", ids);
```

Disregarding whether this example makes practical sense, this query should return a list of objects of type `ChapterWithBookId`, where in that list there is an object for each chapter for all books which have an id, contained in the list of ids set as a parameter.

Comment: You'll want to use the fully qualified name, e.g., `com.foo.bar.MyClass`. Besides this, I don't understand what your question is. Is that code example not working or what exactly are you asking?

Comment: @BenjaminMaurer I just tried to make the example as short as possible (`example.Chapter` was meant to be the fully qualified name). The code example is not working as it gives a syntax error exception at the `new` keyword. It seems like a new is only supported after the `SELECT` statement, but if I add a second `SELECT` statement it also does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's right, you can't have two constructor calls in JPQL - it's not Java, but a custom language and only supports "SELECT NEW".

There are several ways to remedy this:

.1. Have your constructor build the second object as well - admittedly an ugly hack:

```
public ChapterWithBookId(Long bookId, Long chapterId, Long size) {
    this.bookId = bookId;
    this.chapter = new Chapter(chapterId, size);
}
```

.2. Just return the result as a tuple, iterate over the list of tuples and build objects (also ugly).

.3. If you use Hibernate, use Hibernate's ResultTransformer:

```
List<ChapterWithBookId> chapterWithBookDtos = entityManager
.createQuery(
    "SELECT book.id, chapter.id, chapter.size "
    + "FROM " + Book.class.getName() + " AS book JOIN " + Chapter.class.getName() + " AS chapter WHERE "
  + "book.id IN :ids", ChapterWithBookIds.class)
  .setParameter("ids", ids);)
.unwrap( org.hibernate.query.Query.class )
.setResultTransformer(
    new ResultTransformer() {
        @Override
        public Object transformTuple(
            Object[] tuple,
            String[] aliases) {
            return new ChapterWithBookId(
                (Long) tuple[0],
                new Chapter((Long) tuple[1], (Long) tuple[2])
            );
        }
 
        @Override
        public List transformList(List collection) {
            return collection;
        }
    }
)
.getResultList();
```

Here a general article about your options: [Hibernate’s ResultTransformer in Hibernate 4, 5 & 6](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-resulttransformer/)

Blog post about why [ResultTransformer also improves query efficiency](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-use-the-hibernate-resulttransformer-to-customize-result-set-mappings/) by Vlad Mihalcea.

And Vlad also offers the [hibernate-types library](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-resulttransformer/), which has a much nice ListResultTransformer.

I definitely recommend the last two articles and everything Vlad has written - blog and book.

Comment: Thank you. Option 3 looks really good, but unfortunately I am getting the  `org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet` error with cause `java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 ` no matter what SQL syntax I use. Even a very simple syntax does not work when I use multiple constructors. If I only construct a `Chapter` object that way it works.

Comment: @lasbr the ResultTransformer works with the result rows _after_ the query, so it can't produce a `SQLSytnaxErrorException`. I have just tested it and I can put nested constructor calls in the `transformTuple` method. It only matters what result you return.
Anyway, a `SQLSytnaxErrorException` sounds like Hibernate is producing wrong SQL. Check your config to make sure you have the right SQL dialect configured, enable debug printing so you can see the generated SQL query and check it.

Answer (score 0):

As it's defined in the JPA specification (see section *4.8 SELECT Clause*):

> The SELECT clause has the following syntax:
>
> ```
> select_clause ::= SELECT [DISTINCT] select_item {, select_item}*
>
> select_item ::= select_expression [ [AS] result_variable]
>
> select_expression ::=
> single_valued_path_expression |
> scalar_expression |
> aggregate_expression |
> identification_variable |
> OBJECT(identification_variable) |
> constructor_expression
>
> constructor_expression ::=
> NEW constructor_name ( constructor_item {, constructor_item}* )
>
> constructor_item ::=
> single_valued_path_expression |
> scalar_expression |
> aggregate_expression |
> identification_variable
>
> aggregate_expression ::=
> { AVG | MAX | MIN | SUM } ([DISTINCT] state_valued_path_expression) |
> COUNT ([DISTINCT] identification_variable | state_valued_path_expression |
> single_valued_object_path_expression) |
> function_invocation
> ```

So, as you can see the `constructor_item` can not be `constructor_expression`. But you can easy refactor your class `ChapterWithBookId` constructor to construct `example.Chapter` by `id` and `size` and, IMHO, it will make the JPQL much readable.